# Azure VNET to VNET Connection Cannot Connect to VM on Different VNET

Tags: networking, azure

Some of our developers are having issues with speed due to recently cut undersea lines going from their country to our VM datacenter. My thought was to setup a new virtual network located in a different VM datacenter to bypass and reroute their traffic across a faster network, then from that faster network back to the VM location. In theory - basically, how it was previously setup was:

Phillipines to Hong Kong

The new setup would be

Phillipines to West Japan to Hong Kong

In Azure I have two Virtual Networks Gateways setup, one for Hong Kong and one for Japan. I have connected them together using the "Connections" setting, creating a connection to and from both to eachother.

I setup the the correct VPN keys - and downloaded the new client for the Japan VPN.

However, whenever I connect to the Japan VPN i am no longer able to remote desktop into the VM's located in Hong Kong. I dont appear to have any network security group settings that should be blocking this.

My Virtual Networks look like this:

VNHongKong Address Space: 10.1.0.0/24 10.10.0/16

VNHongKong Subnets 10.10.10.0/24 GatewaySubnet 10.10.1.0/14

VNJapan Address Space 10.2.0.0/24 10.20.0.0/16

VNHongKong Subnets 10.2.0.0/24 GatewaySubnet 10.20.1.0/24

I also have both the virtual networks above connected using a Virtual Network Gateway

[image]

Honestly - i'm not anywhere near an expert on this. So i have no idea where i'm messing up - i've followed some online tutorials but i'm stuck just trying to connect to the VMs now that the networks are connected. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

> The new setup would be: Phillipines to West Japan to Hong Kong

For now, Azure does not support this.

Because there is no derived transitive relationship.

For example, location A connect to Location B, location B connect to location C, in this scenario, location A can't connect to location C.

As a workaround, we can create a VM in West Japan, this VM work as a **jumpbox**, then use this jumpbox to connect to Phillipines.